# Set DataFrame Row/Column to 0 if it contains any string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I have some columns where I only have float values, but in some columns there is only a string (sometimes the string also contains numbers if this is relevant).

Now I'm trying to find the max value per column but I ran into some issues because of the strings. I thought it would be better anyways to remove all strings and set them to 0 as this would help working with the data afterwards.

I tried it with `df.loc` but I couldn't find a solution how to check if the row/column contains a string.

Could anyone push me into the right direction?

Comment: Please include a sample data, an expected output and the code that you have tried. Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example. If the strings can be numbers don't you rather want to use them? Or are they strings with a digit?

Comment: Yes, they are strings with a digit, sorry I was a bit unprecise.
I'll get back to you guys in a minute with sample data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, '3'],
                   'B': [4, 'x6', 5],
                   'C': [7, 8, 9]})
```

If you want to consider valid numbers:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').max()
```

output:

```
A    3.0
B    5.0
C    9.0
dtype: float64
```

If you want to drop all strings:

```
df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))).max()
```

output:

```
A    2
B    5
C    9
dtype: object
```